# Public Selectors in root reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I'm building a considerable big app in react with redux as a state manager solution.
I've read about selectors for performance enhance and logic encapsulation and proceeded to implementthem in my sliced reducers.
As Dan Abramov suggested, i started to implement every public equivalent for all my private selectors in my root reducer.
It really does makes a difference both philosophically speaking and regarding code maintenance.
The downsize seems to be this enforced duplication of implementation when creating a selector and my question is regarding this matter.

### Question

I was wondering: could this be avoided (i.e. implementing public selector in root reducer) by directly implementing it with **useSelector** hook?

And if so, is there any drawbacks of this implementation while trying to use it together with **reselect** library?

Comment: `i started to implement every public equivalent for all my private selectors in my root reducer.` I'm not sure what that means, how are you using selectors in your reducer? Can you give an example of the duplication you mention?

Comment: as Dan abramov stated in his [tutorial video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers):

**previate selector** (usually in the related reducer):

`export const getVisibleTodos = (state, filter) =>{ swich (filter) ..... }` 

**public selector** (usually on root reducer with the same name as the private selector)

import { getVisibleTodos } from ./myReducer

`export const getVisibleTodos = (state, filter) => ({
    todos : getVisibleTodos ( state, params.filter ) 
})`

as you can see, there is a public equivalent that takes root reducer state

Comment: In reselect you would do something like: `const selectTodos = state => state.todos` and `const selectVisibleTodos = createSelector(selectTodos,(_,filter)=>filter,(todos,filter)=>...` The way Dan does it is not how reselect works and won't do any memoizing (getVisibleTodos will return a new object every call even when relevant state didn't change).

Comment: Looks like Dan is tightly coupling the command and query (CQRS). Command in redux is middleware and reducers and query are the selectors. A really good explanation of reselect and the role of selectors can be found [here](https://read.reduxbook.com/markdown/part1/07-selectors.html). Note that Dan has not contributed to Redux since 2016 and I'm not sure how old that course is but things have changed a little since then.

Comment: Also check out the comment: "[Needs an update to latest react eco system](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux)"